# Compatibilidad MySql 8.0 y mySql 5.7.x

Tags: php, mysql, apache, servidor

hice una aplicación con ajax, mvc y php para mysql 8.0...llegado el momento de montar la app al server (Windows) me dicen que el mysql es version 5.x lo cual genera problemas de compatibilidad.
¿Que podría hacer para solucioanr este problema? Sugerencias??

Nota: Ya hay mas aplicaciones (muchas) en el server que trabajan con mySql 5.7.x.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Tú pregunta esta basada en opiniones y puede terminar como cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en windows server, pero la logica para mi seria que instalaras 2 versiones de MySQL en tu servidor

1. conserva tu version mysql 5.x y que tus actuales apps sigan apuntando a esa version.
2. crea una nueva instancia de mysql 8 y tu nueva aplicacion apunte a la version 8.

"Just a thought"

Reference:

- Running Multiple MySQL Instances on Windows
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-windows-servers.html